# Cannot access input dom variable in HTML

Tags: php, html, dom, getelementbyid

I have this HTML document ( test1.html ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="VALUE123"><br>

<?php
echo "Hello<br>";
echo "document.getElementById('firstname').value" ;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**The output is:**

```
First name: VALUE123

Hello

document.getElementById('firstname').value    <=====================
```

**How to correct the code** so that the last line of output will show `VALUE123` instead of the variable name itself ?

I have to use PHP ( no Javascript ), and I need to setcookie() inside PHP using the `firstname` variable.

Comment: You want to echo the JS code inside <script> tags.

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to do but your javascript needs to be in a `<script>` tag

Comment: You can't do what you are trying to do. PHP is executed on the server, before your JavaScript is even seen by the client.

Comment: I updated my answer. No js used.

Comment: I think this should work in order to get the value
<?php 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('firstname').value;</script>';
?>
After you get the value you can write into a cookie.
Please let me know if you still not able to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/*
  The PHP setcookie() function sends an HTTP cookie to a client.
  Syntax: setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure)
  Only name and value are requiered
*/

  if ( isset ($_POST['firstname']) )
  {  // Client did send (an other) firstname.
     $fnValue = $_POST['firstname'];
     $expire = time()+60*60*24*3; // 60s 60m 24h 3d
     setcookie('firstname',$fnValue,$expire);
  }
  else
  {
     if (isset($_COOKIE['firstname']))
         $fnValue = $_COOKIE['firstname'];
     else
         $fnValue = "";
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST">
        First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>

   <?php
   if ( strlen($fnValue) > 0 )
   {
       echo "Hello<br>";
       echo $fnValue;
   }
   ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a SCRIPT tag around the document.getelement line. It's considered html now. Try

```
<script>
document.write(document.getElementById("yourfield").value);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a value of a DOM element through PHP. This is not possible unless you make a POST or GET request to the server, where the data is processed and sent back to your client as a response.

Unlike JavaScript, PHP can't see what's going on on the page itself unless you send it to the server first.

Comment: Not even that. OP is trying to execute client-side javascript while the page is still being built by php on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The line document.getElementById('firstname').value is javascript, you cant use it like this.

If you need to print in the html like you did, you could use a little bit of jquery, maybe like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="VALUE123"><br>

<?php
echo "Hello<br>";
?>

<span id="showName"></span>

</body>
<script>
   $('#showName').text($('#firstname').attr('value'));
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what your trying to achieve is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="VALUE123"><br> 
<input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
<?php
echo "Hello<br>";
echo $_POST['firstname']";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Think of the server side (php) as being a bit like building a trainset

and the client side (javascript / html /css) as being like playing with it :)

If you want to add some more track or change the layout you can. But you must stop playing with it first and go back to the construction phase. Or in the case of php build a completely new track based on the data you supplied.

It is possible to modify the live layout while in action. You'll have to read up on ajax for that :)

Comment: I need to use php to set cookie, using the firstname variable, I don't want to use js.

<?php
$value = "my cookie value";
setcookie(document.getElementById('firstname').value, $value);
?>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access JavaScript variables like this. If you want to set a cookie, do it from js, there are ready-to-use tools for that. Look for anything "setcookie JavaScript" in Google. But I think you also need to understand what happens on server side and what's on client side. And it takes a lot more than an answer to explain that in detail.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are trying to print value of `input` then you don't need PHP. It can be done by JavaScript.
2. Obviously your script won't work, because PHP is server side and can't print DOM element. And you are trying to print javascript syntax without `<script>` tag